# How does one go about installing ImageMagick on Google App Engine?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

We have a need to convert the first page of a PDF file to a PNG image to show a thumbnail of the PDF on our website. We've identified this [NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-image) but it depends on Imagemagick. As per [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36253667/imagemagick-on-google-cloud), it appears that you can upload a Dockerfile to install Imagemagick however, it was a Ruby example.

Can someone please help us on how we can install Imagemagick on App Engine Flex Environment for our Node.js application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install new software onto a GCP flexible environment VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39062214/how-to-install-new-software-onto-a-gcp-flexible-environment-vm)

Comment: Ignore the language-specific stuff in any related answer, only focus on the imagemagick snippet - you just need to get the imagemagick package on your system, everything else is irelevant.

Comment: Imagemagick requires the Ghostscript delegate library to convert PDF files. So you might as well just install Ghostscript and use it directly, if that is all you want to do.

Comment: @DanCornilescu I read the thread you sent me but I am not familiar with Docker and don't want to mess up the Node.js environment. I can't find way to first download the default Docker configuration of our app so I can extend it. How do I copy it?

Comment: @fmw42 Thank you! I will make sure I do that!

Comment: @Nag: see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build. I'd also recommend setting up a staging environment app where you can try out stuff.